# Subadditivity of Measure, how to prove

Tags: measure-theory

I want to understand the following inequality, where $B, A $ and $C$ are sets in $X:$

$$ \mu(B \cap A) + \mu((B \setminus A) \cap C) + \mu((B \setminus A) \setminus C) \geq
\mu(B \cap (A \cup C)) + \mu(B \setminus (A \cup C))$$

Thank you

Comment: Is $\mu$ a measure, or just an outer measure?

Comment: I think what we have defined in our notes as measure is conventionally viewed as outer measure. This statement is from the proof that measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ \color{red}{\mu(B \cap A) + \mu((B \setminus A) \cap C)} + \color{blue}{\mu((B \setminus A) \setminus C)} \geq
\color{red}{\mu(B \cap (A \cup C))} + \color{blue}{\mu(B \setminus (A \cup C))}$

The blue parts are equal, since $(B \setminus A) \setminus C = B \setminus (A \cup C)$.

Red parts:

Note that $B \cap A$ and $(B \setminus A) \cap C$ are disjoint sets - first is contained in $A$, the other contains no elements of $A$. By subadditivity,

$\mu(B \cap A) + \mu((B \setminus A) \cap C) \geq \mu((B \cap A) \cup ((B \setminus A) \cap C))$

However, $(B \cap A) \cup ((B \setminus A) \cap C))$ is the same set as $B \cap (A \cup C)$, which ends the proof.

Comment: I think that was a very good explanation. Thank you.